# HTML5 get scaled canvas size

Tags: css, html, canvas, html5-canvas

My css looks like this:

```
#Canvas {
width: 100%;
max-width: 548px;
height: auto;
}
```

And it scales my image how I want it.

However when I call `canvas.width` it will always return the same width even if my browser window is really small. Why can't I get the size from the `canvas`?

I need the size because I check for `mouse hover` by `startX = percentX * canvas.width` 
And it is not correct because `canvas.width` is static.

Cheers!

Comment: look here http://jsfiddle.net/dauzqcj6/2/

Comment: Try `canvas.scrollWidth`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `canvas` element has it own `width` and `height` attributes, so editing the `width` and `height` in `css` will only scale it but the `canvas`' attributes will remain the same. So to change the `canvas` size you will have to resize it by `JavaScript` with `onresize` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `canvas.scrollWidth` to get the `width`. Run `code snippet`
 in `Full Page`

```js
function getWidth()
{
    var can = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var wid = can.scrollWidth;
    alert(wid);
}
```

```css
#myCanvas {
width: 100%;
max-width: 548px;
height: auto;
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>

<input type="button" value="Get Width"  onclick="getWidth()"/>
```

Comment: Thanks mate but i dont get this to work with mouse.

I use: e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft; to get the draw position but its not on my mouse

Comment: I didn't know that and you also didn't mentioned it in your question. This method works for me. I have created a fiddle demo. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sx2sm5ux/1/) and sorry but I didn't understand what you really need. If you could explain me through [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sx2sm5ux/1/) fiddle.

Comment: Thanks! No I didnt think I had problem with mouse however I noticed that it had problems too. I tried the code in my project and somehow scrollwidth return 0 every time except when you resize your browser window.

Though the fiddle works great..

Edit! Never mind, I found the thief and it was my tab lib. 

Thanks mate for the help!